# fgets & strstr do not seems to work?

Tags: c

Here is the whole code, the problem is in the 25th line. If I give the value withe strcpy, the code works. If I try to read the value with fgets, the strstr in the 23th line doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct tk {
    char name[60];
} tk;

int main() {
    tk* array;
    array = (tk*) calloc(1, sizeof(tk));
    int k;
    char c[60], h[60];
    strcpy(array[0].name, "A B");

    void find(char *c, tk *array) {
        for (k = 0; k < strlen(array[0].name); k++) {
            h[k] = tolower(array[0].name[k]);
        }
        printf("%s %s", array[0].name,c);
        if (strstr(h, c) != NULL) printf("1");
    }
    fgets(c, 60, stdin);
    k = 0;
    for (k = 0; (k < strlen(c)); k++) {
        c[k] = tolower(c[k]);
    }
    find(c, array);
    free(array);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `for (k=0;` --> `for (int k=0;`, at least.

Comment: You do realize that line numbers are not shown, right? A good idea is to mark with a code comment the place you're talking about, to make it easier to help you.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is not suitable problem description. Please read about [mcve], [edit] your question and provide input you gave, output you got, and output you expected.

Comment: are you actually using nested functions? that's non-standard.

Comment: `c` which was obtained from `fgets` contains a newline, but `"A B"` does not - so `strstr` will not find the substring.

Comment: Thanks everybody. The problem was the the new line. Now can you help me how to delete it from c? As you can see I'm not a coding genius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fgets` man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf.aspx) says

> fgets reads characters from the current stream position to and
>   including the first newline character, to the end of the stream, or
>   until the number of characters read is equal to n – 1, whichever comes
>   first.

That is why you get a match when you set up `c` with `strcpy` but not with `fgets`.

You can remove the newline like this

```
c [ strcspn(c, "\r\n") ] = 0;
```

and if there is no newline present, this is harmless.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after the `fgets`. You need to remove the `\n` after reading it from `stdin`

```
fgets(c, 60, stdin);
strtok(c, "\n"); // add this statement
```

Tokenize the `c` array after reading it from stdin. Should work fine after this. Cheers!